# How can I define something like OR in jQuery's selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Here is my current code:

```
$(".close_btn").click(function(e) {
        $(".box1").fadeOut(100);
        $(".box2").fadeOut(100);
});
```

As you see, currently, when you click on `.close_btn`, both `.box1` and `.box2` will be hidden. Now I want to use `$(this)` and `.closest()` to hide just one box *(the parent of clicked `.close_btn`, there are two `.close_btn`)*. I mean I want something  like this:

```
$(".close_btn").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest(".box1" OR ".box2").fadeOut(100);
});
```

Is doing that possible?

Comment: `$(this).closest(".box1, .box2")` ?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Yes .. great. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a comma to separate multiple selectors:

```js
$(".close_btn").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest(".box2, .box1").fadeOut(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">
  <button class="close_btn">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="box2">
  <button class="close_btn">Close</button>
</div>
```